# SurveyMonkey API Console Not Working

Tags: surveymonkey

The SurveyMonkey API Console was working for me until a day or two ago. Whenever I click on AUTHORIZE on the console with my API Key and username, it opens up a new window with this reply

The authorization request failed:

Missing required parameter: api_key

I've checked my account status and it's active, not restrictions or anything. I can't do any testing on the console without authorizing my api key on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: One idea - contact SurveyMonkey support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be addressed to SurveyMonkey support


Comment: Sorry, SurveyMonkey just asks everyone to ask on stackoverflow first before sending an email to support.

Answer (score 1):

The old API console has been deprecated, try the new one.  You can access it directly here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api_console